# SwiftUI Conditional View Transitions are not working

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

Consider the following code:

```
class ApplicationHostingView: ObservableObject {
  @Published var value: Bool
}

struct ApplicationHostingView: View {
  // view model env obj
  var body: some View {
    Group {
      if applicationHostingViewModel.value {
        LoginView()
          .transition(.move(edge: .leading)) // <<<< Transition for Login View
      } else {
        IntroView()
      }
    }
  }
}

struct IntroView: View {
  // view model env obj
  var body: some View {
    Button(action: { applicationHostingViewModel.value = true }) {
      Text("Continue")
    }
  }
}

struct LoginView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello World")
  }
}
```

#### ISSUE

In this case, I see my transition from IntroView to LoginView work fine except for any of the animations. Animations inside IntroView based on the conditionals seem to be working fine but transitions that change the entire screen don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. change `group` to `ZStack`
2. add animation somewhere.

   ```
               class ApplicationHostingViewModel: ObservableObject {
                     @Published var value: Bool = false
                   }

                   struct ApplicationHostingView: View {
                     // view model env obj
                       @ObservedObject var applicationHostingViewModel : ApplicationHostingViewModel
                     var body: some View {
                       ZStack {

                         if applicationHostingViewModel.value {
                           LoginView()
                             .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                         } else {
                           IntroView(applicationHostingViewModel:applicationHostingViewModel)
                         }
                       }
                     }
                   }

                   struct IntroView: View {
                     // view model env obj
                        @ObservedObject var applicationHostingViewModel : ApplicationHostingViewModel
                     var body: some View {
                       Button(action: {
                           withAnimation(.default){
                               self.applicationHostingViewModel.value = true} }) {
                         Text("Continue")
                       }
                     }
                   }

                   struct LoginView: View {
                     var body: some View {
                       Text("Hello World").frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight:  .infinity)
                     }
                   }
   ```

Comment: Changing `Group` to `ZStack` enabled transitions added to the `Text` view inside `LoginView` for example. However, I already have a transition: ` .transition(.move(edge: .leading))` on `LoginView`. Why does that not work?

Comment: There is no container to hold the transition

Comment: Okay. Can you give an example of a way to provide a transition for the entire way with a container?

Comment: I guess I am unsure how to define a transition context here to enable a container view that can handle this transition.

Comment: Wait I just tried your example and that seems to work great. I was previously not getting that behavior even with a ZStack. Will comment here shortly.

Comment: You can also use `.offset()` instead of `.move()`, in my tests it works better in a `ZStack`.